# Google Analytics API - Specify urls with numbers in filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics-api

I am trying to configure a [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) in the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference), but I don't manage to extract urls containing numbers.

> ex: /comptable-opcvm-debutant-**3**

My configuration:

```
ga:medium==organic;ga:PagePath==~.[0-9]+
```

Here the report status:

```
=> Cannot read property "0" from undefined.
```

Comment: I guess you need to use `ga:PagePath=~.*[0-9]+` (`=~` means *Contains a match for the regular expression*). Please check.

Comment: ga:PagePath==~.*[0-9]+ doesn't work

Comment: Even with one `=`? What about `ga:PagePath%3D~.*[0-9]+`?

Comment: unfortunately not, Invalid value 'ga:PagePath%3D~.*[0-9]+' for filters parameter.

Comment: hi guys, no one else?

Comment: Did you try URL encoding the whole input? Like `ga%3Amedium%3D%3Dorganic%3Bga%3APagePath%3D%7E.%2A%5B0-9%5D%2B`? Or `ga%3Amedium%3D%3Dorganic%3Bga%3APagePath%3D%3D%7E.%2A%5B0-9%5D%2B`? If that does not work, try to get rid of `+`: `ga:PagePath=~.*[0-9]{1,25}` (no idea if this Google API has the quantifier limitations as some other Google APIs). Otherwise, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

filtering by Page Path with a digit at the end works for me without any problems after a few changes in the original expression. I was testing it in [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/):

- **metrics:** ga:pageviews
- **dimensions:** ga:pagePath
- **filters:**    ga:pagePath=~^[^?]+\d+$

*Example of results:*

```
/071620716207162                            1
/JZepeda13277JZepeda13277JZepeda13277       1
/help/how-do-i-send-photo-or-file-expert-0  48
/help/topics/141                            47
...
```

[image: Query Results]

Comment: The expression works in Query Explorer but not in the GA add-on in Google Sheets. The report failed due to this error: "Cannot read property "0" from undefined"

Comment: @mike1789 it works for me in Google Spreadsheets as well. http://pasteboard.co/20KriKiF.png